# Is there a way to define different pytest "profiles" in setup.cfg or pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I want to define two different "profiles" for my tests and I'm using setup.cfg. I want to know if it's possible to configure this all under `[tool:pytest]`.

I want to do more than just change markers I want to change other settings too.

The two different executions would look something like this and might include even more diverging args and settings in the future (I want to be able to define them arbitrarily):

```
profile_name: unit # "profile_name" doesn't exist just using as example of the kind of thing I'm looking for
    addopts = --verbose -m "unit" --capture=yes --disable-pytest-warnings
    python_files = *_test.py
    testpaths =
        tests/unit
```

And:

```
profile_name: integration # "profile_name" doesn't exist just using as example of the kind of thing I'm looking for
    addopts = --verbose -m "integration" --capture=no
    python_files = *_test.py
    testpaths =
        tests/integration
```

It would be great if I didn't have to create two pytest inis or just override everything via command line. I'd like to be able to run a command akin to `pytest --profile="unit"` and centralize all my pytest settings in setup.cfg.

Is such a thing supported?

I also use a `pyproject.toml` so if this is supported there I would be able to use that file too.

Comment: I don't know if that's possible, but perhaps the problem could be solved from another approach.  First I need to ask, why have different profiles in pytest?  From the context of your question, it would appear you're running "unit" vs "integration" tests.  These appear to exist in different folders.  Which means they are completely different test suites.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [tox](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/)?